# Fastboot flash system.img error

Tags: android, android-source, sony, fastboot

When I try to flash via fastboot system.img (from my custom AOSP build) to Sony Xperia Z3 I get the following error:

```
# fastboot flash system system.img 
sending 'system' (584106 KB)...
OKAY [ 18.294s]
writing 'system'...
FAILED (remote: size too large)
finished. total time: 18.297s
```

Z3 has about 2GB system partition and I have no idea why flashing fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the solution:

```
BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE
```

in BoardConfig.mk was larger than it should be. Changing it fixed the issue.

Comment: May i ask what exactly is BoardConfig.mk ? I don't find this kind of file in my computer.

Comment: BoardConfig.mk is configuration file used when you compile your own Android ROM.

Comment: Ok, i face the exact same problem as you. I have Asus Zenfone Selfie. I can't find such file in my computer. Can you provide me with something relevant, eg some other file, so i can edit that and increase partition size ?

Comment: By editing BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE you only give the compiler information how big is your device's system partition so that it can build system.img with appropriate size.

Comment: Ok. How do i edit BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE ?

Comment: Assuming that you build your own ROM, the file is located upon your_aosp_source/device/your_device_vendor/your_device/BoardConfig.mk

Answer (score 10):

This forces fastboot to automatically sparse files to a given range in size K | M | G, in this case 256M

```
fastboot flash –S 256M system PATH_TO_SYSTEM.img
```

Comment: This method also does not work. It gives the following output: sending sparse 'system' (259493 KB)...
OKAY [  8.138s]
writing 'system'...
FAILED (remote: size too large)
finished. total time: 8.141s

Comment: Faced the same issue @Lawiusz specifying the -S parameter didnt change my situation

Answer (score 4):

Use newer fastboot version that allow sending packages sperated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a newer fastboot version. New bootloaders support downloading system.img in parts.